Gradle build failed to produce an .aab file. It's likely that this file was generated under D:\DEV\spluswms\build, but the tool couldn't find it
flutter run works fine. apk build works too. key.jks exists and I've checked the sdk path and flutter path. But appbundle doesn't build. I'm going crazy... Please help me. If you need anything else, I'll upload it!

The apk file I thought was built is not installing. I think the build file is somehow corrupted. Please give me some hints!!!!

error img :
enter image description here
flutter doctor -v img:
enter image description here/
enter image description here

Was the file generated where it suggests?

The apk file is created just fine. However, the aab file is not created. This is because the build itself is not working.

Please do not post terminal text output as screenshot. Just copy and paste the text into your question and format it as code.
